# Unable to load drivers for Wireless card or Nvidia card in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, nvidia, resolution

I've looked through countless posts and tried several suggested lines of code for the terminal.

I have a Dell Precision M50 I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on.  When I first installed, the display was pixelated and "broken" up looking.  I played around with several post suggestions trying to get the Nvidia drivers loaded.  My display looks better, but I only have 800x600 resolution now.  I'm also trying to install a Linksys WPC54G V2 PCMCIA card because the internal wifi card isn't capable of anything but WEP.

I'm not great with linux, and I've tried everything I can find or think of.  If anybody could help, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the wireless card, but not the graphics one. Firstt, open Dash and type "Additional Drivers". Then, open the program and activate all inactivate drivers there. I cannot help you if the installation goes wrong, but I hope it doesn’t!

Comment: I checked Additional Drivers.  There are none listed to select from.  Thanks for answering though.

Comment: Try and go on their website, see if they have support for Linux (I  think Nvidia might have something)